# Azure AD Domain Service for secondary Azure AD tenants?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have three Azure AD Tenants and one is marked as the default directory.

[image]

When I create an Azure AD Domain Service, the Directory name is already filled in and cannot be edited.

[image]

Why can I not choose between my three tenants?

Comment: ¿log into another tenant and do the same thing?

Comment: Only one is linked to my subscription so I am not able to provision anything when logged into the others. But I was able to create the others in the portal. My question is why I cannot select those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I create an Azure AD Domain Service, the Directory name is
>   already filled in and cannot be edited.

It is a by design behavior, the Directory name will filled with the current Directory name, we can't change it manually.

> Only one is linked to my subscription so I am not able to provision
>   anything when logged into the others.

We can change to other directory to create AAD DS, but Azure require a subscription with that directory.

So, if you want to create AAD DS with other directory, we need create a subscription for that directory.

Here is the screenshot about create AAD DS:
[image]